# django admin callable readonly_field verbose name

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using callable for a read-only field in Django admin, like this:

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('real_value','estimated_value', )
    readonly_fields = ('estimated_value', )

class Item(models.Model):
    real_value = models.CharField(... , verbose_name=u'a nice label')

    def get_estimated_value(self):
        return ...some value...
    estimated_value = property(get_estimated_value)
```

Now, I just want to add some nice label for estimated_value to admin form. Can this be (reasonably) done? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an exmaple

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    estimated_value = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
    class Meta:
        model = Item
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.has_key('instance'):
            instance = kwargs['instance']
            self.initial['estimated_value'] = instance.estimated_value
```

Then add that form to the admin

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Item
    form = ItemForm
```

Comment: Well, this works as expected as long as the "estimated_value" field is *not* on readonly_fields list. When i put it on the list, it reverts to old behavior (generic label, no input field at all).

Comment: I ended up using custom ReadOnly widget in Form field much like this one: http://lazypython.blogspot.com/2008/12/building-read-only-field-in-django.html  Thanks for getting me on the track :)

Answer (score 7):

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('real_value','estimated_value', )
    readonly_fields = ('get_estimated_value', )

class Item(models.Model):
    real_value = models.CharField(... , verbose_name=u'a nice label')

    def get_estimated_value(self):
        return ...some value...

    get_estimated_value.short_description = 'Your verbose name'
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, it's just a single line of code and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Define a custom [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) and attach the custom field for estimated_value there. Connect this ModelForm to your ItemAdmin using the form attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, if you'd like it to show on the change list you can just add the field to the admins list_display:

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        model = Item
        form = ItemForm
        list_display = ('real_value', 'estimated_value', )
```